# proving statements about kernel, image and linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let V be a vector space and let $T:V\to V$ be a linear map.
>
> Let S be a linear map: $S=T\circ T$ i.e. $S:V\to V \ , \ S(x)=T(T(x))$
>
> 1. Prove that S is a linear map.
> 2. Prove that $Ker(T)\subseteq Ker(S)$
> 3. Prove that $im(S)\subseteq im(T)$
> 4. Prove that $im(S)=im(T)$ iff $Ker(T)= Ker(S)$

1. So in order to prove it's a linear map we need to use $T(\alpha v_1+v_2)=\alpha Tv_1+Tv_2$. Therefore: $T(T(\alpha v_1+v_2))=T(\alpha Tv_1+Tv_2)$ and that's it (?).

As for the following statements I have no idea how to begin...

Comment: Ccan you show that if $x\in Ker T$ ,then $x\in Ker S$

Comment: For the first statement, you need to show that $S(\alpha v_1+v_2) = \alpha Sv_1 + Sv_2$. That is, that $T(T(\alpha v_1+v_2)) = \alpha T(Tv_1) + T(Tv_2)$.

Answer (score 1):

1. $T(T(\alpha v_1+v_2))=T(\alpha Tv_1+Tv_2)=\alpha T(Tv_1)+T(Tv_2)$ (just as you thought.)
2. Suppose $v\in Ker(T)$. Then $Tv=0$, hence $Sv=T(Tv)=T(0)=0$. So $Ker(T)\subseteq Ker(S)$.

3 and 4 are corollary to 2.